# What is Renly's eye colour?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the *A Song of Ice and Fire* series first it is mentioned by Sansa that Renly's eye colour is green. He wears green clothes to bring the colour of his eyes.

But later it is mentioned that his eye colour is blue like his elder brother Robert. Which is true? Did the writer miss it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

GRRM admitted it was a mistake. He also said earlier that Renly's eye colour is blue-green, which can appear one or the other to the viewer depending on what Renly's wearing.

> He did note with some amusement that his readers catch his mistakes
>   for him (Renly's eyes being green once, then blue, and then calling
>   them 'blue-green eyes that changed color depending on what he wears'
>   as an out). Ditto with various horse gender oopses.
> <sub>[***US SIGNING TOUR (ALBUQUERQUE, NM) - The Citadel SSM***](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/US_Signing_Tour_Albuquerque_NM)</sub>

You must note of course that the POV style chapters are not [100% accurate](https://www.nownovel.com/blog/unreliable-narrator/). Sansa for example also *thinks* that the Hound kissed her before leaving King's Landing when in fact he never did.

Answer (score 22):

George R. R. Martin has explained the inconsistency by saying that Renly's eyes are blue-green and change color depending on what he wears.

Quote from [westeros.org](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/US_Signing_Tour_Albuquerque_NM) :

> He did note with some amusement that his readers catch his mistakes for him (Renly's eyes being green once, then blue, and then calling them 'blue-green eyes that changed color depending on what he wears' as an out).